# Subview of a custom UIView not appearing in UI Tests

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I have a custom `UIView` that has a `UITableView` as a subview.
I have set the accessibilityLabel and accessibilityIdentifier for both the `UIView` and the `UITableView`. However, I can only query the `UIView` on my UITests and the table view does not appear at all. I have also set the `isAccessibilityElement` to `true`.

```
  public lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return tableView
  }()

  // MARK: - Initialization

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    commonInit()
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
  }

  // MARK: - Private Methods

  private func commonInit() {
    isAccessibilityElement = true
    accessibilityLabel = "Filter View"

    tableView.isAccessibilityElement = true
    tableView.accessibilityLabel = "Filter View Table"
    tableView.accessibilityIdentifier = "Filter View Table"

    addSubview(tableView)
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[tableView]-0-|", options: .alignAllLeft, metrics: nil, views: [ "tableView": tableView ]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[tableView]-0-|", options: .alignAllLeft, metrics: nil, views: [ "tableView": tableView ]))
  }
```

I am accessing the controls in my UITests like:

```
let filterView = app.otherElements["Filter View"] // Custom View
XCTAssertTrue(filterView.exists)
let filterTableView = filterView.otherElements["Filter View Table"] // Table View as Custom View's subview
XCTAssertTrue(filterTableView.exists)
```

Comment: I am not aware of how your tableView is initialized. Is your tableView initialized before you are accessing it via identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `filterView.tables` instead of `filterView.otherElements` ?

`let filterTableView = filterView.tables["Filter View Table"] // Table View as Custom View's subview`

Comment: Did you try to look for your table view by adding a breakpoint and checking with the debugger ?